# Why use the subversion integrated on Intellij to merge the main code to the branch without prompting a conflict but overwriting the code

Tags: intellij-idea, svn

I have a branch and a trunk in subversion.When I merge from trunk to brank,It always overwrite the conflict code but without prompting.And It seems like based on the trunk code.How can I solve this problem.

[image: This is my branch,then click the "subversion working copies infomation" and select the tab "merge from trunk",then click the tab "merge all]

[image: and the second picture is a example,It is a file history in my branch,the left version number 21791 is before merge from trunk ,the right version number 21791 is after merge from trunk.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conflict occurs only in cases when the same lines are changed in a different way in branches. Judging by the screenshot, there were no conflicting changes.

IntelliJ never automatically resolves conflicts. It relies on the command-line svn client, and if `svn merge` fails with the merge conflicts, reports accordingly in the UI. If `svn merge` finishes fine, no conflicts are reported.

Check if merging with svn in the command line reports any conflicts.